# How to swap the column bit values in a table with a single update query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have a table with a column (`bit`), I just want to update the column value from true to false and false to true in a single query. I simply want to swap the values, any help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method:

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET BitColumn = BitColumn ^ 1;
```

`NULL` values, if any, will remain `NULL`;

Comment: Or just BitColumn = 1-BitColumn? Kudos for using bit-operation though ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this,

```
UPDATE dbo.TableName  
SET     ColName =  CASE  
                        WHEN ColName  = 0 THEN 1 
                        WHEN ColName = 1 THEN 0 
                    END 
WHERE   <your where clause (if needed)>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simply :

```
UPDATE TableName
SET ColName = ~ColName
```

Description of the operator : [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173468%28SQL.90%29.aspx)